# PHP editing file not working

Tags: php

Simple question.. this code doesn't work, I am trying to replace all the content in isoff.php file and put "ash is cool" in the content, then exit it out at the end just to make sure we know that its actually worked and the new content has been added to that file,. but the content doesn't change.

```
$fname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/website/content/isoff.php";
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($fhandle,"ash is cool");
fclose($fhandle);

exit(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/website/content/isoff.php"));
```

Help?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of this file.  Maybe there is a (hidden) error/warning.

Comment: whats the permission of isoff.php ? you can turn on error_reporting  to see the bug

Comment: How yo bypass 'failed to open stream: Permission denied in' on iis?

Comment: What error message is displaying

Answer (score 1):

It is good idea to run `exists` and `is_readable` to check whether the file you're looking for is there. Also check if the returned value is not null and use `w+` instead, good way to debug what is happening out there.

```
if (fopen('', 'w+') != null)
```